# Why is there only one way to glue projective space from affines?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have been somewhat shaky as to how exactly we glue $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ out of affine schemes. The explanation of this always seems somewhat guided by knowing what we want...

Take for example $\mathbb{P}_k^1= \operatorname{Proj} k[u,v]$, then we use the standard procedure of gluing (via a unique gluing function) together the affine patches $D^{+}(u)$ and $D^+(v)$ along $D^+(vu)$.  I don't have a problem with this, however...

Is it possible for there to exist some other set of affines that glue together to form $\operatorname{Proj} k[u,v]$?

Comment: doesn't the idea of Proj construction largely hinge on not choosing distinguished affine patches? (cf. Vakil) (disclaimer: i don't know great details about it.)

Comment: There are many ways of gluing. For example, take $f,g$ homogeneous polynomials in $u,v$ such that radical of the ideal $(f,g)=(u,v)$. Then $D^+(f),D^+(g)$ will give you affine patches which can be glued along $D^+(fg)$ to get the projective line.

Comment: Proj is a global construction. It doesnt presuppose any affine gluing. What one shows is that the scheme you get by Proj construction is the scheme obtained by gluing standard affine  schemes in the way familiar from topology.  You can take any set of generators for the irrelevant ideal and use them to glue affine pieces and get proj.